# Get epoch time and replace old value

Tags: python, discord

I have a Python script which connects to discord for a 'custom' rich presence. Every time I want to use it, I have to edit the script to enter in the current Epoch time so the counter on Discord starts from when I run the script. I was wondering if there was a way to automate this, having the script get the current time value and replace the old value which was there on run. May not be possible.

Comment: The OS is usually in charge of keeping time, at least for most modern OS, so you could leverage the Python `time` library.

Comment: This is a summary of the script what I have on there:          

import rpc
import time



client_id =
rpc_obj = rpc.DiscordIpcClient.for_platform(client_id)
print("RPC connection successful.")

time.sleep(5)
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    activity = {
            "details": "Listening to: Blur",
            "timestamps": {
            "start": 1542148125
            },
            }
        }
    rpc_obj.set_activity(activity)
    time.sleep(30)

Comment: @Nebulous show your code in your text

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.utcnow()
epoch_time = int((now - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds())
```

This should collect your current epoch time.

Comment: It returned this error upon running, also, thanks.

`epoch_time = int((now - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds())
NameError: name 'now' is not defined`

Comment: Do you also reckon there's a way to get it to detect what song iTunes is playing? I'm sorta working on it